# Is it possible to generate getters and setters functions based on some sort of attribute automatically?

Tags: python, function

I have a "user" class that has hundreds of attributes and I'm not sure if it is best to use a class and have to manually create hundreds of getters and setters  which just set values to a key in a dict or just use the dictionary directly. Having the getters and setter seems to be the best way to abstract the internal representations of the attributes so I can change from a dict to whatever I need to later, I just don't want to expose those keys in case they need to change.

For example we have a few attributes in class foo:

```
class User(object):
     attributes = {"fname": None,"lname": None,}
```

I would like something to let you call  `get_fname()` and have it return the value of `fname`
or `get_lname()` and have it set the value of `lname` without having to define the functions.
Same way with the setters,  `set_fname(value)` would set fnames value and so on. I'm not sure if this is even possible or if I'm just overthinking the problem and missing a simple solution.

Comment: Why do you want to use explicit getters and setters at all? That's very uncommon and usually a bad idea in Python.

Comment: (Also, having hundreds of attributes in a class seems like a bad idea to start with.)

Comment: Okay, looking at your post, you say you want to abstract the internal representation (and it sounds like you might already have some weird internal representation?). It sounds like you're approaching the abstraction issue wrong - if your class's public interface involves interacting with *hundreds* of attributes, your class is probably the wrong abstraction no matter whether or not you have getters and setters for those attributes.

Comment: This is a Java-nism.  Don't do it. See  [Python is not Java](https://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html), this was probably an pre-obituary for Chandler.  however, you could `self.__dict__.update(**self.attributes)` to initialize your instances from the dict.  100s of attributes is a big code smell tho.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply define all of the attributes in the class.  Each instance will appear to have all of the class variables as members (at the default value), and if a value is set for an attribute on any particular instance it will update the instance `__dict__` rather than the class `__dict__`.

```
class User(object):
    fname = ''
    mname = ''
    lname = ''

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

user1 = User(fname='Foo', lname='Bar')
user2 = User(lname='Public', fname='John')
user2.mname = 'Q'

print(f"{user1.fname} {user1.mname} {user1.lname}")   # prints "Foo  Bar"
print(f"{user2.fname} {user2.mname} {user2.lname}")   # prints "John Q Public"
```

As other comments have said, having so many variables in a single object is something that is best avoided if possible, and having explicit getters & setters is un-Pythonic.
If you need getters and/or setters, you can always add them later if & when you need them; Java won't let you do this, but Python will.

Answer (score 0):

For this *particular* case, you can simply use the dict to initialize a bunch of variables, assuming you have some situation like

```
class User:
    attribute_init = {"fname": None, "lname": None, "mi":""} # and many more
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self.__dict__.upate(__class__.attribute_init)
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname

user = User('Foo', 'Bar')
print(f"{user.fname} {user.mi} {user.l}")
```

Although, I would heed the advice in the comments about this being major code smell. Number of attributes and this dict-based

Comment: Replacing the namespace doesn't really do anything useful. You're immediately overriding the values from `attribute_init` anyway. (Also, replacing `self.__dict__` instead of calling `update` interferes with shared-key optimizations.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes, I can't really think of a good situation of where you one would do this, and this example simply serves to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's usually not necessary in Python to have getter and setters, if you're going to implement them anyway, you could minimize a lot of the repetitive code by using a class decorator as shown below:

```
def add_attributes(attributes):

    def class_decorator(cls):
        ''' Create getter and setter methods for each of the given attributes. '''
        for attr_name, inital_value in attributes.items():

            def getter(self, name=attr_name):
                return getattr(self, name)

            def setter(self, value, name=attr_name):
                setattr(self, name, value)

            setattr(cls, attr_name, inital_value)
            setattr(cls, 'get_' + attr_name, getter)
            setattr(cls, 'set_' + attr_name, setter)

        return cls

    return class_decorator


@add_attributes({"fname": None, "lname": None,})
class User(object):
    pass


user = User()
user.set_fname('Lawrence')
user.set_lname('Dimmick')
print(f'{user.get_fname()!r}')  # -> 'Lawrence'
print(f'{user.get_lname()!r}')  # -> 'Dimmick'
```